# Regex for fixed length floating point number

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, linqpad

I am using this regular expression to match 8 digits signed floating point number.

```
  string exp= "12345678";
  string regEx1="^([-+]?[(\\d+\\.?(\\d+)?)]{1,8})($)";
  Regex topRowRegx = new Regex(regEx1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
  Match matchResult = topRowRegx.Match(exp.Trim());
```

irrespective of -/+ and . symbols it should match 1 to 8 digits number.

It should match -1.2345678, 123.45678, +12.34, 1.2, 1, 12345678, 1254.
There should be at least one digits before decimal and after decimal, if decimal symbol presents.

The above expression working fine but it is failing when I use -/+ or . with 8 digit number.
Can you help me how to identify exactly 8 digits and leave remaining symbols count?

**UPDATE:**
Vasili Syrakis answer solved the above problem. Just for curiosity, why this is not giving correct result?

```
   string exp = "text> -9.9999999 \"some text here\"";
   var resultNumber = Regex.Match(exp, "[-+]?(\\d{1,8}|(?=\\d\\d*\\.\\d+?$)[\\d\\.]{1,9})");
   ("Result:"+resultNumber.ToString()).Dump();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Altered regex:

```
^[-+]?(\d{1,8}|(?=\d\d*\.\d+?$)[\d\.]{1,9})$
```

#### Escaped version:

```
^[-+]?(\\d{1,8}|(?=\\d\\d*\\.\\d+?$)[\\d\\.]{1,9})$
```

### Explanation

It will either find an 8 digit number
OR it will find 9 instances of either a period or number... ONLY if there's 1 period separating the numbers. The 9 is to account for the period.

### Online demo

<kbd>http://regex101.com/r/kD1oT6</kbd>

Comment: It is accepting more than 8 digits. checked for -12345678.90

Comment: The modified one working fine but it is accepting these number "-.12345678" adn "-12345678."  There should at least one digit before and after decimal number

Comment: Thank you very much Vasili Syrakis. It is working fine now. This one also works ^[-+]?(\\d{1,8}|(?=\\d+\\.\\d+)[\\d\\.]{1,9})$

Comment: Excellent :) Glad to hear it

Comment: Sorry, ^[-+]?(\\d{1,8}|(?=\\d+\\.\\d+)[\\d\\.]{1,9})$ will fail for this number 11.0.1. Your answer is correct.

Comment: Why this expression failing? string exp = ">-9.9999999:\"some text here\"";
var resultNumber = Regex.Match(exp, "[-+]?(\\d{1,8}|(?=\\d\\d*\\.\\d+?$)[\\d\\.]{1,9})");
("Result:"+resultNumber.ToString()).Dump();

Comment: Your answer is not working for the original question if I add some text before and after the number.

Comment: You would need to remove the `^` and `$` marks. Those mean "beginning and end of the string", which would rule out possibility of other text. Removing those might mean the entire regex changes, but you can try it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
^[+-]?(?:(?=\d+\.\d+$)[\d.]{3,9}|(?=\d+$)\d{1,8})$
```

Basically it has two regex are OR'ed together. First one is checking for pattern line `xx.xx`, means digits at the both side of the dot. Which means it can have minimum 3 to maximum 9 in length.

Second one is trying to match the digits `xxxx` in format. Which means it can have 1 to 8 in length.

You can get more explanation of this regex from [this link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl).

Comment: I have modified regex like this to match my scenario ^[+-]?(?:(?=\d+\.\d+$)[\d.]{1,8}|(?=\d+$)\d{1,8})$. But it failing for this number -1234.5678

Comment: @Sree Is there any reason why the proposed regex (not the one you modified) fails on `-1234.5678`?

Comment: @Sree your modification is wrongfully done I must say. Please see the description at my answer to know why I used `{3,9}` instead of your `{1,8}`.