# Regex for matching a floating point number of fixed width

Tags: python, regex, floating-point, scanf

## Short

I am looking for a regular expression capturing the longest possible floating point number up to n characters. It should be able to directly replace C format specifiers like "%5f" in C's scanf function.

## Examples

For n=5, we want to capture

```
string       captured group
123        ->   123
1.23       ->   1.23
123456     ->   12345
+12.34     ->   +12.3
-12.34     ->   -12.3
1.2-3      ->   1.2
1.2.3.4    ->   1.2
```

## Background

The above behaviour is similar to C's "sscanf" function with "%5f" as format specifier.
From the manpage: "Reading of characters stops either when this maximum [n in our case] is reached or when a nonmatching character is found, whichever happens first."
I am trying to build a python analog to scanf. There are existing projects like [this one](https://github.com/joshburnett/scanf), but without support for the maximum field width.

## My approach

My question is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526696/regex-for-fixed-length-floating-point-number).

I tried the following regex:
`((?=[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?)[\d\.+-]{1,5})`

It consist of a lookahead, checking the format of the number, and a following character class with an interval, restricting the length of the captured group.
The problem lies in the last example above, where the lookahead correctly matches only the first part of the string, but the interval extends up to the trailing '-3'.
Do you have any suggestions? Can we create a regex, where the interval refers only to the characters matched by the lookahead?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What about `+12.34`?

Comment: See the updated examples above.

Comment: Why is .5 undesirable from ......5?

Comment: You could just use [scanf](https://pypi.org/project/scanf/)

Comment: @dawg This is the package I linked in my question. :) To my knowledge, it does not implement the field width for floats yet. If we will find a solution here, I will open an Issue or Pull request there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could possibly get along with just

```
^(?:-[\d.]{1,4}|[\d.]{1,5})
```

if your column only has these strings. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/fBw8cc/1/).
Note, that this expression would also allow sth. like `...5`. If you have these sort of strings, you'd need to make the expression more strict.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! My mistake, I will have to clarify my question. The strings above are just  examples, indeed, we want to avoid matches like `....5` or `1.0.0`. I am looking for a regex which can directly replace format specifiers like "%5f", producing the same results as scanf.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
^[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?<!.{6})
^[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?<!.{6})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/unLqCI/3). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[+-]?` - an optional `+` or `-`
- `\d+`  - one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d*)?` - an optional occurrence of `.` and zero or more digits (one or more digits if you use `\d+`)
- `(?<!.{6})` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there are six chars other than line break chars immediately to the left of the current position.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I like the idea of implementing the "below or equal 5" requirement as negative lookbehind. Nevertheless, in order to act as a direct replacement of a "%5f" format specifier in a format string, we cannot assert that the number we are looking for is at the start of the string.  E.g. `ab%5f` replaced with `ab([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?<!.{6})` and applied to `ab123456` will only match 123 instead of 12345. I see that my question is still not properly formulated. Do you see what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: @Necko That means you need to explicitly define match boundaries. If it is not start of string that is a start of a match, what is it? Just to provide a gist: see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/unLqCI/2) where the left-hand boundary is either a start of string, or a non-word char, and not a digit+`-`.

Comment: What I finally want to achive is to limit the number of characters in the captured group to at most n(=5), counted not from the beginning of the string, but from the position of the regex engine when entering the capture group for the first time. I am not familiar enough with regular expressions to decide whether this is generally possible. Another example would be the format string `1.2%5f`, translated to regex `1.2(our capture group)` and applied to `1.234.5678`, resulting in `34.56` being captured.

Comment: @Necko As I said, you need to know your match boundaries, there is no other way. See `[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?<!(?<![\d.+-])[\d.+-]{6})` and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/unLqCI/4) to understand what I mean.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. For now, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/joshburnett/scanf/issues/17) on the [gitub project I linked in my question](https://github.com/joshburnett/scanf) (and mentioned by @dawg). I will give an update here if the issue is resolved/closed.